# Filling out abstract class members by deriving from concrete class

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, class-design

Let's say I have an interface that inherits from another interface (pure abstract class)

```
class BaseInterface
{};
```

Then another interface builds upon BaseInterface

```
class ExtendedInterface : public BaseInterface
{};
```

Now, I have a concrete class that implements BaseInterface:

```
class Base : public BaseInterface
{};
```

Now, I want to implement ExtendedInterface, but since I already have Base I want to fill out the BaseInterface members with base. E.g.:

```
class Extended : public ExtendedInterface, public Base
{};
```

This doesn't seem to work. I get complaints that I cannot instantiate extended since it is an abstract class. The only way I can get it to work is by using virtual inheritance, but then I get compiler warnings about inheriting via dominance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What's the problem ?

With your multiple inheritance, `Extended` inherits two times from `BaseInterface`.  This means that there are two independent `BaseInterface` subobjects:

- one is inherited via the concrete `Base` class, which has overridden all the pure virtual functions.
- but the other is inherited via `ExtendedInterface` class, which is still abstract.

[image]

In consequence, as some subobjects of `Extended` still have pure virtual functions, your class is still an abstract class that can't be instantiated.

## How to solve it ?

As despite the multiple inheritance you apparently expect to have only one `BaseInterface`, you need to use virtual inheritance:

```
class BaseInterface                                       
{ virtual void test()=0; };                              // abstract class

class ExtendedInterface : public virtual BaseInterface   // virtual inheritance
{};                                                      // abstract class

class Base : public virtual BaseInterface                // virtual inheritance
{ void test() override {} };                             // concrete class

class Extended : public ExtendedInterface, public Base   // multiple 
{};                             // thanks to virtual inheritance, concerete class
```

With this logic,  there will be only one `BaseInterface` in `Extended`, with virtual functions overridden, and you can instantiate it.

Here an [online demo](http://ideone.com/WfCz8Z)